# Angular 7 - Lazy Loading not Working with Service Worker

Tags: angular, lazy-loading, service-worker, angular7, angular-service-worker

I deployed my node.js / Angular application on an AWS EC2 Ubuntu instance. When opening the project in a browser, all lazy loaded modules don't work. The modules never complete loading, although they start loading.

---

The weird thing about this is, that when deploying the app to Heroku or testing it with localhost everything works fine. (In production build).

Here is what the network tab looks like when deployed to the AWS EC2 instance (not loading lazy modules):
[image: network activity]

Here is what the network tab looks like when deployed to Heroku (works fine):
[image: network activity]

Here is what the network tab looks like when run on localhost (works fine):
[image: network activity]

---

The lazy loading only works when removing my service worker.

**app.routes.ts**

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'auth',
    loadChildren: './auth/auth.module#AuthModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'seller',
    canActivate: [guards.AuthGuard, guards.SellerGuard],
    loadChildren: './features/seller/seller.module#SellerModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'shopping',
    loadChildren: './features/shopping/shopping.module#ShoppingModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'products',
    loadChildren: './features/products/products.module#ProductsModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'me',
    canActivate: [guards.AuthGuard],
    loadChildren: './features/me/me.module#MeModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'search',
    loadChildren: './features/search/search.module#SearchModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'business',
    loadChildren: './features/business/business.module#BusinessModule',
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    loadChildren: './features/users/users.module#UsersModule',
  },
  {
    path: '**',
    redirectTo: ''
  },
];
```

**node-server.js**

```
// many other configurations
app.use('/api', api)
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).sendFile(path.join(__dirname, './client/index.html'))
})
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`• Server launched   on port`, port)
    console.log(`• Server running in ${prod ? '  production' : '  development'} mode`)
    console.log(`• • •`)
})
```

---

I can't really post detailed code, because it's a very big project and I don't know what causes the error. So let me know if I should add some specific file(s).

---

**Service Worker implementation**

`app.module.ts`

```
@NgModule({
    // ...
    imports: [
        ServiceWorkerModule.register('ngsw-worker.js', {
            enabled: environment.production
        })
    ],
)}
// ...
```

`ngsw-config.json`

```
{
  "index": "/index.html",
  "assetGroups": [
    {
      "name": "app",
      "installMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/favicon.ico",
          "/index.html",
          "index.html",
          "/*.css",
          "/*.js"
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "name": "assets",
      "installMode": "lazy",
      "updateMode": "prefetch",
      "resources": {
        "files": [
          "/assets/**"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "dataGroups": [
    {
      "name": "",
      "urls": [
        "https://www.some-domain.com/api/*",
      ],
      "cacheConfig": {
        "maxSize": "15",
        "maxAge": "6h",
        "timeout": "10s",
        "strategy": "performance"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Looks like there's something wrong with service worker. Could you include some block of codes where you set the service worker ?

Comment: I've added it :)

Comment: try prevent the registration of service worker and see if it works.

Comment: It works fine without the service worker! Have you any idea how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove your updateMode prefetch from your assets.